# MMS With Twilio Using Google App Script Is not working

Tags: google-apps-script, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to send a MMS using Google App Script and Twilio. For some reason Twilio is not sending the MMS. No errors are being logged. Everything seems to be operating as expected except I never receive the image. Am I missing something?

```
function sendText() {

  var messagesUrl = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC88563f5e7f405a10c6caa109002d8ac8/Messages.json";

  var payload = {
    "To": '+11234567890',
    "Body" : 'hello',
    "mediaUrl": 'https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2899/14341091933_1e92e62d12_b.jpg',
    "From" : "+11234567890"

  };

  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : payload
  };
  options.headers = {    
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("YOURACCOUNTSID:YOURAUTHTOKEN")
  };

  var value = UrlFetchApp.fetch(messagesUrl, options);
  Logger.log(value)

}
```

and this is the response I am getting

```
{
  "sid": "SMccaca54f12754f1691ad7af61bbc6dc",
  "date_created": "Wed, 24 Oct 2018 17:42:23 +0000",
  "date_updated": "Wed, 24 Oct 2018 17:42:23 +0000",
  "date_sent": null,
  "account_sid": "AR88563f5e7f301a10c6cba109112d8ac8",
  "to": "+11234567890",
  "from": "+11234567890",
  "messaging_service_sid": null,
  "body": "hello",
  "status": "queued",
  "num_segments": "1",
  "num_media": "0",
  "direction": "outbound-api",
  "api_version": "2010-04-01",
  "price": null,
  "price_unit": "USD",
  "error_code": null,
  "error_message": null,
  "uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/AR88563f5e7f301a10c6cba109112d8ac8/Messages/SMcaaca81f20754f1691ad7afc71bbc6dc.json",
  "subresource_uris": {
    "media": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/AR88563f5e7f301a10c6cba109112d8ac8/Messages/SMcaaca81f20754f1691ad7afc71bbc6dc/Media.json"
  }
```

Comment: Is there anything in your [Twilio debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/debugger) or anything in the [message logs](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/logs)? Are you definitely sending to a US or Canadian number?

Comment: Yep, definitely sending to a US number. The body comes through fine. It's just the mediaUrl part. Nothing is showing up in the Twilio debugger. According to Twilio, everything is sent correctly.

Comment: In that case I'd collect some message SIDs where this has happened and send them to [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) they can track down where the image went to.